# How do I enable new account notification emails (to the administrator)?

Tags: admin, users, user-registration

As an administrator, receiving an email when a user registers to my blog is important. How do I enable this feature?

Comment: Isn't WordPress doing that by default. WordPress always sends notification email when a new user is registered on your website.

Comment: It isn't for me! It hasn't since I got it and to my surprise noticed that there were 8 spam user signups waiting approval before I enabled activation with BuddyPress. I get all the emails from BuddyPress but don't get the new user registration emails to my admin email... wp_mail works! I tested it with a plugin filter.

Comment: In that case buddy your website is not working fine. Either mail/notifications are not configured properly on plugin or some other function is overwriting this basic functionality. Because we all get registration notification emails.

Comment: Everything works, I even ran check-mail plugin. Just am not and have not (since installation) been receiving new user registration emails.

Comment: It was Gmail. I got it. Something is up with them. Thanks. Closing the question.

Comment: Hi @CharlesT. To close the question please either accept one of the answers or write up your solution and select that as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is enabled by default.
Check that WordPress is sending emails at all, you might have problem with the SMTP settings.
Where is your website hosted?
Did you check the spam?...

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your mail address from your profile. If it is true;
2. Check your junk/spam folder. If there is nothing;
3. Check your mail() function on your server. Because if you are using shared hosting, it can be disabled.

If it's disable but you have personal server;

4.1. Turn it on in your php.ini

If it's disable and you have shared hosting;

4.2. Use STMP. If you don't know STMP;
5. Download 'WP-Mail-SMTP' plugin and configure it.